# Get Owner(s) in .NET Azure Active Directory groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an email account which is a Security Group where there are few members in it. I am trying to figure out the email address of the **owner** of the group but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Below is the source code

```
    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));
    var group = (Group)await activeDirectoryClient.Groups.Where(u => u.Mail == "email@domaincom").ExecuteSingleAsync();.
    var groupFetcher = activeDirectoryClient.Groups.GetByObjectId(group.ObjectId);
    var membersResult = groupFetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync().Result;
    var ownerResult = groupFetcher.Owners.ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

After I execute this code, I can see the members of the Group but w**hy ownerResult variable is always empty**? **How can I retrieve the owner of the group?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am testing using the code below(`Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` with version `2.1.1`)and it works well for me. Please ensure that the group have the owners assigned.

```
var group = (Group) client.Groups.Where(u => u.Mail == "email@domain.onmicrosoft.com").ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
var groupFetcher = client.Groups.GetByObjectId(group.ObjectId);
//var membersResult = groupFetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync().Result;
var ownerResult = groupFetcher.Owners.ExecuteAsync().Result;
foreach (var owner in ownerResult.CurrentPage)
    Console.WriteLine(((Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User)owner).DisplayName);
```

You can check it from Azure portal like figure below:
[image]

If the owner exists, I also suggest that you capture the request using Fiddler to check whether the response is expected.